# Escape @ in Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

Im using perl to match a password against a regex in a bash script.

While testing the regex for the password, I got to this problem:

This works :

```
perl -e 'if ( "Bomba\@2071"  =~ /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{8,}$/ ) { print 1; } '
```

While this never matches :

```
perl -e 'if ( "Bomba@2071"  =~ /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{8,}$/ ) { print 1; } '
```

As you can notice, it works because I escape the @ symbol. I had never seen something like this in another programming languages and after being stuck with this for over an hour, I found the reason by mere chance.

So, my question is, Whats going on here? Why do I need to escape an odd character like @?

Comment: Either of `use strict;` or `use warnings;` would have told you what the problem is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because `@` in perl denotes to an [array variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html), so without escaping it what follows would be interpreted as an array variable.

Besides escaping `@`, you can also use single quotes instead of double quotes, e.g. `'Bomba@2071'`, so that the string would not be subject to interpretation, although in this case it would create a new problem since you're using single quotes to quote the entire perl source in a shell command. So stick to escaping in this case.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response!

Comment: You could use a single-quoted literal without actually using single-quote: `q{Bomba@2071}`